# Google Docs Mail Merge script not working as of last week

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

A mail merge script that we use for 5 of our google docs stopped working last week - a similar thing happened a few weeks ago when DocsList became obsolete and I was able to fix it, but now it has stopped working again.

```
var docTemplate = "15kvC3M8b0Me3Vi3GwErQvG60BlTC0qAHMXrlc3Ocky8";  
var docName     = "RefundByCheck"

function onFormSubmit(e) { 
   var first_name = e.values[1];
   var last_name = e.values[2];
   var customer_email = e.values[3];
   var brand = e.values[4];
   var amount = e.values[5];
   var purchase_date = e.values[6];
   var customer_address = e.values[7];
   var rep_name = e.values[8];
   var order_number = e.values[9];
   var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
                .makeCopy(docName+'_'+order_number)
                .getId();
   var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
   var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
   copyBody.replaceText('keyFirst', first_name);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyLast', last_name);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyBrand', brand);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyAmount', amount);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyPurchaseDate', purchase_date);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyAddress', customer_address);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyRep', rep_name);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyOrder', order_number);
   var todaysDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy"); 
   copyBody.replaceText('keyTodaysDate', todaysDate);
   copyDoc.saveAndClose();
   var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId);
   var theblob = pdf.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B3nrCN8N5OBcRnlWaUlHZUxZNE0');
   var movefile = folder.createFile(theblob);
   DriveApp.removeFile(movefile);
   var subject = "Text goes here" + order_number
   var body    = "Hello " + first_name + " " + last_name + "," + "<br /><br />" 
   + "Text goes here" + "<br /><br />"
   + "Text goes here"
   + "Text goes here"
   + "Text goes here"
   + "Text goes here"
   + "Text goes here"
   + "Text goes here"
   + "Text goes here"
   + "Text goes here"
   var cc = "test@test.com";
   MailApp.sendEmail(customer_email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf, cc: cc}); 
   DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

I have a feeling that Google updated something else and I need to change my code, but I'm not sure - I am pretty sure that it is something broken in this section due to the summary of failures notification I received: 5/25/15 8:59 AM   **onFormSubmit We're sorry, no servers are currently available. Please wait a bit and try again.** (line 41, file "RefundByCheckCode")

```
   var movefile = folder.createFile(theblob);
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Still no luck despite extensive research on the issue. I could really use a hand here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be [Issue 3206](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3206), "Sending mail with attachment of Drawing (as PDF) consistently fails". Visit that defect and star it for updates. There doesn't appear to be a new scenario in your script, but if you have any additional info that might help the Googler who is responsible for fixing this problem, you could add a comment to the issue tracker.

Since the problem seems to arise some time after a script has been running successfully, and is then persistent, I suggest duplicating your script, and decommissioning the original.

Edit: OP was able to get around the problem by deploying a replacement of their template file.

Comment: Thank you for the info - I have already tried duplicating the entire document as well as the script, but this did not work unfortunately. Hopefully there will be a fix soon.

Comment: I feel for you. The issue was first reported more than two years ago, so I wouldn't count on a fix anytime soon. Another idea: de-authorize the script, then go through authorization again. There's no reason it should help... but then, there's no reason for the failure in the first place.

Comment: I was able to get the script to work making a new copy of the template doc and using that as the template. If I use the ID from the old template, the script does not work, but using the new template seems to allow it to work. Not sure what the heck was going on but Mogsdad's suggestion of creating copies of the documents seems to work (specifically the template in this case)